# Angular 2 access component from another component

Tags: ionic-framework, angular, components, ionic2, viewchild

I have a page with two components on it:

```
Page({
    template: '<ion-navbar *navbar class="contact_navbar">
                    <ion-title>Loan Calculator</ion-title>
                </ion-navbar>
                <ion-content><ck-auto-loan-calculator type="normal"></ck-auto-loan-calculator></ion-content><ck-keypad id="keypad"></ck-keypad>',
    directives: [[ckAutoLoanCalculator], [Keypad]]
})
export class LoanCalculator {}
```

Now inside ck-auto-loan-calculator I have a button that has: `(click)="showKeypad()"`

The showKeypad() function used to have `let k = this.app.getComponent('keypad');` and this was accessing the `<ck-keypad>` component

Now since ionic changed to beta 7 and angular changed to RC, I get the following error:
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setControl' of undefined

How can I make the keypad component accessible in the Ck-auto-loan-calculator component ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ionic 2 `getComponent` has been deprecated, you can pass the component as an input to another component.

You can pass it from the template using this syntax:

```
<ck-auto-loan-calculator type="normal" [keypad]="keypad"></ck-auto-loan-calculator>
<ck-keypad #keypad></ck-keypad>
```

Then in the `ckAutoLoanCalculator`

```
  @Input() keypad: Keypad
```

anywhere in your `ckAutoLoanCalculator`

```
  this.keypad.open() // assumes there's a public method on keypad component called open
```

[Plunker for passing components as inputs](http://plnkr.co/edit/FOSOxJTHoEJg9yrLbCJv?p=preview), did the example with a modal component for illustration